# Keyboard Listener for Moving Sprite not working in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, keylistener

I am making a classic space shooter type game for a GUI project, using JPanels and swing etc. I have a multi-layered main menu with a button for play and exit etc, however, the issue I am having is in my DrawPanel class which paints all the graphics for the game. This class has one giant paint component method that activates on a timer every 500 ms, and renders blinking stars on a background, renders the spaceship, and renders falling enemies. The stars are blinking, the enemies are falling but the spaceship is not moving at all and I have to use the "a" and "d' keys. The question: how can I move the ship? Below is an extremely summarized version of that rendering class to keep it simple, the paint component class is full of other things however including generating blinking stars.

```
 public DrawPanel(int x, int y) 
{
t = new Timer(500, new ActionListener(){@Override public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){repaint();}});

this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
        @Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { ship.keyPressed(e);System.out.println("keypressed");}
        @Override public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { ship.keyReleased(e);System.out.println("keyreleased");}
    });
t.start();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics Graphic)
{
    super.paintComponent(Graphic);
      drawShip(Graphic);
    drawEnemy(Graphic,10);

}

private void drawShip(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.drawImage(ship.getImage(), ship.getX(), 
        ship.getY(), this);
}
```

This is the spaceship class that is called by the drawship method, and that explains the calls by variable "ship" in the previous code.(Note: there are no compiler errors or runtime errors in anything)

```
public class Spaceship {
private int x = 780;
private int y = 850;
private Image image;

public Spaceship() 
{

   ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("spaceship.png");
    image = ii.getImage(); 

}

 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key ==KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        x += -10;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        x+= 10;
    }


}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
   {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        x += 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        x += 0;
    }


    }
 }
```

My thought process on this was that the keyboard would be active at all times and anytime it registered a press it would modify an x so that the next time the ship would be drawn it would be in a different position. However it would be bound by the same time that the enemies and background are bound by and wouldn't fluidly move side to side now that I think about it, but I have no clue how to make a separate paint component, timer, and repaint as that's the only way I know to paint. Also 
I do realize I haven't done bound checking on this for the ship movement but that shouldn't be an issue right now as it's not even moving a centimeter yet, much less out of bounds, and it is not even printing the debug statements in the listener.
All of my classes are added to panels which have been bound to buttons and tabs in my main menu by adding it all to default constructor of the main method, so this is how the entire game executes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
 GalagaRipOff main = new GalagaRipOff();
}
```

Comment: Edit: I added the keylisteners to the main class instead of keeping it in a different class that was added to main method. To my understanding key listener in a a sub panel or something will not be active in my current JFrame? Basically adding my listeners to main method and then setting appropriate booleans and get methods to modify ship class from main method I was able to get the key listeners to work.